# How to know what android rom should i download?

Tags: android, android-rom

The stock rom for my device arent avaliable for free from the manufacture source, but at sale from 3party sources. And the custom roms arround the internet confuses me ... If i download a custom rom 'Lolipop', would it work in any device ? If so, why does the stock rom even exists ? Isnt the stock rom specially developed for an specific device, because of its own unique hardware ? If i download the stock rom of an 'x' device, would it work fine in my 'y' device ?

And how can i know until wich version my device's hardware is capable to work ?
Is hard to choose ...

Comment: That's rather a question for our Android sister site – and hast been asked there many times over. See e.g.: [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/17152/16575) // [Can I install a ROM made for a different device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/35925/16575) // [Why are there not generic phone OS installers?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/63630/16575) and more at the `rom` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google LineageOS, type in your device and downloaded the latest Android release for your phone. LineageOS is completely open-source and backed up by tons of documentations about how to manage this.